# How to clean this CSV into one instead of 4 different CSV using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, for-loop

Original Data is like this, with all of the "Channels" and other data combines in the same columns:
[image]

The final result needs to be like this:
[image]

Currently my for loop is producing this, separating all of the "Channels" data into 4 different .csv:

This is my Current code:

```
from os import path
from numpy import append
import pandas as pd


#Name of File
account= 'TTI_0021AA.csv'

#Calls 
header_list = ["Name","Channel","DT","Usage",'Delete1', 'Delete2']
df= pd.read_csv(account, names=header_list)
#print(df)

#See the Number of Channels  
splitChannels= df['Channel'].unique()
#print(splitChannels)


for value in splitChannels:
    df1 = df[df['Channel']== value]
    df1.drop('Name', inplace=True, axis=1)
    df1.drop('Delete1', inplace=True, axis=1)
    df1.drop('Delete2', inplace=True, axis=1)
    df1 = df1[["DT","Channel","Usage"]]
    outputFileName= "Channel" + str(value) + ".csv"
    df1.to_csv(outputFileName, index=False)
```

How can I change the for loop to insert the parsed data as new columns in one .csv?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to create a new dataframe, and get the output out of your loop.

so create a new dataframe, then append columns on for each new channel, then at the end, after your loop is exited you should be able to export the singular csv. I am not sure if you can do it without modifying the loop you currently have.

But the short is, it's exporting a new file for each channel because that's what you've told it to do. And it looks like it's not writing a new column to the current dataframe because you haven't told it to do that either.

Also, since you're breaking the data by channel, I would suggest grouping the data that way and not having a "Channel" column, it's redundant and creating too much repetition. Unless of course your requirements are to it do it that way.

Ideally you'd have

| DT_Ch_1 | Usage_1 | DT_CH_2 | Useage_2 | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |